# Putnam 2009 B1 (rational number as factorial)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

> Show that every positive rational number can be written as a quotient of products of factorials of (not necessarily distinct) primes. For example, $ \frac{10}9=\frac{2!\cdot 5!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!}.$

I used the idea:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\prod x_{k}!}{\prod y_{j}!} \implies a = \frac{(b)\cdot\prod x_{k}!}{\prod y_{j}!}$$

Then I said suppose it holds for:

$$\varphi = \{1, 2, 3.... a-1\}$$

Then since for $a > 1$:

$$\frac{a}{2} < a-1$$ It follows from strong induction,

$$\frac{a}{2!} = \frac{(b)\cdot\prod x_{k}!}{\prod y_{j}!}$$

$$\frac{a}{b} = 2! \cdot \frac{ \prod x_{k}!}{\prod y_{j}!}$$

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Wouldn't an induction require that $\frac a{2!}$ is an integer?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, consider $a$ even then $\frac{a}{2!}$ is an integer. If $a$ is odd,not prime $\frac{a}{3}$ is an integer. Multiply by $3 = \frac{3!}{2!}$.  I only have a problem when $a$ is prime, can you help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Proposition.** Every prime number can be written as quotient of prime factorials (pfq for short).

*Proof.* We have
 $2=2!$ (or $2=\frac{2!97!}{97!}$ if you insist on a denominator).
Let $p>2$ be a prime and assume all primes $<p$ can be written as pfq. Since $p=\frac{p!}{(p-1)!}$ and $(p-1)!$ is a product of primes $<p$, we conclude that the denominator and ultimately $p$ can also be written as pfq.
$_\square$

**Corollary.** The original claim.

*Proof.* Just write down the prime factorization of numerator and denominator and use the proposition for each prime. $_\square$

Comment: I see. But this only works for prime numbers. How would a combination of the method I showed and this be?

Comment: @Amad27 Did you see the corollary in Hagen's answer? Its very easy (trivial?) to extend the result for primes to positive rationals.

Comment: @Thomas, I know. But I was just wondering if there was the other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

First reduce the proposition to

> Every natural number $n$ can be written in the form
>   $$\frac{\prod_i p_i!}{\prod_j q_j!}$$
>   Where $p_i$ and $q_j$ are primes.

This can be shown using an induction approach. Now $\frac ab$ for a positive rational means $a,b\in\mathbb N$ so you can just write
$$\frac ab = \frac{\prod_i p^{(a)}_i! \prod_j q^{(b)}_j!}{\prod_k p^{(b)}_k! \prod_l q^{(a)}_l!}$$